# Generate True False boolean enumerable in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq

I believe it is a simple problem. I want to generate a LINQ enumerable to use in a selectmany function. This is what I want to do

```
    var completeMonthsList = (from p in MonthList                                         
                               select new
                               {
                                  p.Month
                               }).SelectMany(ml => boolList.Select(bool =>

                new
                {
                    Month = ml.Month,
                    isConditonal= bool
                }
                )
```

I tried generating a list and adding the two boolean values to it but it gives a error.

> NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

The Code used is below

```
    List<Boolean> boolList = new List<Boolean>();

            boolList.Add(true);
            boolList.Add(false);
```

Now the only other option I can think of is having two lists, one with a `selectmany => false` and one with a `selectmany => true` and then do a concat on them to get a complete list.

Is there a function in linq like the [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) function which generates booleans or another way to generate the booleans without requiring the `concat`?

Comment: What LINQ provider is this using (i.e. LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If i havent misunderstood your question try something like this

```
var rsult = (from p in MonthList).Tolist()
             .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i, 2)
            .Select((s, ii) => new { Month = s.Month, isConditonal = ii % 2 == 0 ? true : false })).ToList();
```

I hope this will help.And I am expecting you are fetching MonthList from DB if not then you can skip ToList() after MonthList.